# Postgres and Sequelize - SequelizeUniqueConstraintError

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "wf"."WorkflowAssignationContact" (
"workflowAssignationId" int4 NOT NULL,
"contactId" int4 NOT NULL,
"contactNumber" varchar NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "WorkflowAssignationContact_contactId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("contactId") REFERENCES "public"."contacts"("id"),
CONSTRAINT "WorkflowAssignationContact_workflowAssignationId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("workflowAssignationId") REFERENCES "wf"."WorkflowAssignation"("id"),
PRIMARY KEY ("workflowAssignationId","contactId"));
```

As I can understand this is a table with two primary keys so for me that means that it will only prevent me from save if the pair (contactId and workflowAssignationId) are equals to other already saved right?

Well what's happened is that when I try to save with this query:

```
INSERT INTO "wf"."WorkflowAssignationContact" ("workflowAssignationId", "contactId", "contactNumber") VALUES (9, 1887, 'cfs:078286556');
```

I got this error:

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "WorkflowAssignationContact_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key ("workflowAssignationId", "contactId")=(9, 1887) already exists.

The table is completely empty...

Verified ids 9 exists in the related table and also 1887 is valid Id in the contact tables.

The sequelize model is this one:

```
@Table({timestamps: false, schema: 'wf'})
export class WorkflowAssignationContact extends Model<WorkflowAssignationContact> {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ForeignKey(() => WorkflowAssignation)
    @Column
    workflowAssignationId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => WorkflowAssignation)
    workflowAssignation: WorkflowAssignation;

    @PrimaryKey
    @ForeignKey(() => contacts)
    @Column
    contactId: number;

    @Column
    contactNumber: string;

    @BelongsTo(() => contacts)
    contact: contacts;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

The table is being created with a sequelize migration:

```
await queryInterface.createTable("WorkflowAssignationContact", {
                workflowAssignationId: {
                    allowNull  : false,
                    primaryKey : true,
                    type       : Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    references : {
                        model : "WorkflowAssignation",
                        key   : "id"
                    }
                },
                contactId: {
                    allowNull  : false,
                    primaryKey : true,
                    type       : Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    references : {
                        model: {
                            tableName : "contacts",
                            schema    : "public"
                        },
                        key: "id"
                    }
                },
                contactNumber: {
                    allowNull : false,
                    type      : Sequelize.STRING
                }
            }, { schema: "wf"});
```

Comment: Does this INSERT query work if you execute it directly w/o Sequelize?

Comment: No it does not work in sequelize neither directly in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue,

Sequelize is indeed working correctly, during the object creation:

```
const workflowAssignation = await WorkflowAssignation.create(obj, { include: [ { model: WorkflowAssignationContact }, { model: WorkflowStepAssignation, include: [ WorkflowStepAssignationHasUser]}] });
```

I'm using create passing the body object that already contained the contacts records, so at the time I'm trying to do the bulk insert it failed because they are already created.